# Math to rotate a point around an origin in Go

Tags: go, math, geometry, 2d

Cannot remember the math to use from school however I want to rotate a point around an origin using Go/Golang.

Very basic idea below, **x,y is the origin** (center) and **x2,y2 is the point** on the circumference of the circle that moves. I want x2,y2 to rotate 360 around x,y continously.

```
x:= 10 // center x
y:= 10 // center y

x2 := 20 // rotating point x
y2 := 20 // rotating point y

xchange := ??? What math to use to calculate the change in x
ychange := ??? What math to use to calculate the change in y
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Found the answer here myself which works fine, just needed to convert it to Go https://gamefromscratch.com/gamedev-math-recipes-rotating-one-point-around-another-point/

Answer (score 2):

You can parametrize a circular orbit around the point (x0, y0) with radius r as

```
x(t) = x0 + r cos(t)
y(t) = y0 + r sin(t)
```

You can work out r based on the two points you begin with. From there it’s just a matter of smoothly increasing t to simulate the progress of time.

Comment: Thanks for the help though was not able to understand that, anyway managed to convert this answer to something that worked https://gamefromscratch.com/gamedev-math-recipes-rotating-one-point-around-another-point/

Answer (score 0):

To rotate about an arbitrary center:

- translate the designated center of rotation to (0,0)
- rotate about the (0,0)
- translate (0,0) back to the designated center.

Example code:

```
// translate center of rotation to (0,0)
dx := x_in - x_center
dy := y_in - y_center

// rotate about (0,0)
c := math.Cos(angle)
s := math.Sin(angle)
rotx := dx * c - dy * s
roty := dx * s + dy * c

// translate (0,0) back to center of rotation
x_out := rotx + x_center
y_out := roty + y_center
```

Comment: thanks though also was over my head